# equalsIgnoreCase method isn't working with JOptionPane (or Scanner) input

Tags: java, string, java.util.scanner, equals, joptionpane

```
    // ask user to enter name of state capital
    String answer = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is the capital of " + 
            question + "?");

    // verify name of state capital is in citiesarray
    boolean isPresent = false; int stateNum = 0;
    System.out.println(answer); // troubleshooting line
    for (int i = 0; i <= 49; i++) {
        String city = citiesarray[i];
        isPresent = answer.equalsIgnoreCase(city);
        System.out.println(city); // troubleshooting line
        System.out.println(answer.compareTo(city)); // troubleshooting line
        System.out.println(isPresent); // troubleshooting line
        if (isPresent == true) {
            stateNum = i; break;
        }
    }
    if (isPresent == false) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "That is incorrect. Please try another round.");
        return;
    }
```

Whenever I run this code, I end up with all false booleans for every iteration of the loop, no matter what capital I enter. It seems like the `compareTo` output for whatever city that should return true for `equalsIgnoreCase` is always -1, but I don't know how to use that to identify and solve my problem.

I've tried a couple of different things and found that with Scanner, it seemed to work as long as answer didn't contain a space, but that doesn't seem to matter with `JOptionPane`, and regardless, I need this to work no matter what the capital of the state is.

Comment: What are the values in `citiesarray`?  Also, I would change the SOP lines to something like `System.out.println("'"+city+"'");` to check for erroneous spaces.

Comment: First of all the way you are validating the answer is incorrect. neverthless what are the values you have in `citiesarray` and what is the value you input to the InputDialog?

Comment: The values in citiesarray are the fifty state capitals read from a *.txt file.
Changing the SOP line prints only the second apostrophe, for reasons I don't understand.
Could there be some sort of escape character in the array values that I'm missing? Is that a thing?

Comment: try to do it like this
isPresent = answer.equalsIgnoreCase(city.trim());

Comment: on a side note, put the declaration of String outside the loop String city = citiesarray[i];

Comment: How are you reading the file?  It sounds like that is where the problem is.

Comment: Using trim worked! Thank you!
I didn't move the String declaration out of the loop, though. Wouldn't that keep it from updating in the loop, which is why it exists in the first place? Or were you just saying initialize it outside the loop first?

Comment: @Jobin, what do you mean the way I'm validating the answer is incorrect?

Comment: @user2327805 yor are simply storing some answers in an array, there is no mapping to question and answers.

Comment: @Jobin, mapping how?

Comment: @Lucky He means that as long as the user enters a city that is in your file, they will be told they got the correct answer, whether it is the correct answer or not.

Comment: Oh, yeah, no. I wrote it to check if the city was in the array at all and then check if the indexes matched later. The rest I had just separated as a different task, so i didn't include it in the code here. I suppose there might be a way to do both steps more succinctly, but I'm not concerned about it for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

The posted code is working perfectly, I just added two lines and copied above code into the main method, after adapting the limit of the loop:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] citiesarray = { "New York", "Paris", "Berlin", "Brasilia" };  // not real ones, but wanted one with space
    String question = "somewhere";

    // ask user to enter name of state capital
    String answer = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is the capital of " + 
            question + "?");

    // verify name of state capital is in citiesarray
    boolean isPresent = false; int stateNum = 0;
    System.out.println(answer); // troubleshooting line
    for (int i = 0; i < citiesarray.length; i++) {
        String city = citiesarray[i];
        isPresent = answer.equalsIgnoreCase(city);
        System.out.println(city); // troubleshooting line
        System.out.println(answer.compareTo(city)); // troubleshooting line
        System.out.println(isPresent); // troubleshooting line
        if (isPresent == true) {
            stateNum = i; break;
        }
    }
    if (isPresent == false) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "That is incorrect. Please try another round.");
        return;
    }
}
```

The problem must be somewhere else, probably how `citiesarray` is being declared/initialized.

Comment: Thank you!
I'm not sure how to adapt the file-reading part of the code to fix whatever's going on there, but Freak's suggestion to use trim worked at the level of comparing the Strings!